# Can I override the OutputPath of a project on the solution level from within the VS2015 IDE?

Tags: msbuild

My goal is to override the `OutputPath` property on all projects in a solution to be `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\`. I would like to set this from within the VS2015 IDE.

I don't want to change the OutputPath in the .csproj or .vcxproj files (I know how to do this and it's not my intention to make a permanent change to the project files). I just need a local change for the moment to build.

I know I can accomplish this from the command line in a Developer Command Prompt by setting `/p:OutputPath=$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\` on msbuild. Ideally, would like to be able to do this from within the IDE. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to set `OutputPath` in a Developer Command Prompt and then launch VS2015, open the solution, and build:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"`

Comment: Why did you downvote this? It might be useful information for somebody else. Please justify yourself.

Comment: Have an upvote to counter it, your answer does make sense.

Comment: @PerryC I didn't understand what you did here. Did you build the sln from the Developer Command Prompt with the custom OutPutPath and then start a new VS instance?

Comment: There are elegant ways to do this instead of passing env vars from command line. Please check documentation of Directory.Build.props and Directory.Build.targets files. These are auto included by MSBuild system.

Answer (score 1):

Typical way of doing this is to import the same msbuild file in each project, and set OutputPath in that imported file. Disadvantage: project files need to be modified, it's not 'from within VS'. Advantage: has to be done once only, works on commandline as well as in VS, works for everybody, is pretty flexible and extensible. For example you could override OuputPath based on whether or not a certain file is present on the system, or a certain environment variable, or hostname, etc.

The answer you gave also works, though is also not from within VS. But the biggest drawback for me is that if you give your project to someone else they won't have an overriden output path, i.e. such modifications cannot really be put in version control. Of course if that's what you are after than it's fine.

Comment: I completely agree that this is very far from ideal. It's a temporary workaround as builds/compilers/projects are being upgraded. Thank you for your answer.